# I published a Google Sheets add-on, but it's not appearing in the G Suite Marketplace list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-addons

I just published a G-Suite add-on, following all the steps from this document:

https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons

I have a listing in the Chrome Web Store:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jolojoedfljdjiibjffeaehjaiofjkfg/publish-accepted?authuser=0

I also followed the steps for the GSuite Marketplace, but I'm stuck at the "Publish" step.

No matter what I fill in in this form, the 'Publish' button stays grayed out. I am not sure if this is expected, but it's also not clear what I can do to get this final step to work.

[image]

Comment: Does it remain greyed out even after you fill in everything that's been highlighted in Red?

Comment: @SourabhChoraria, yes, but I have an update. So I will answer my own question here.

Answer (score 0):

After sitting on this for a couple of days, my add-on started to appear in the marketplace. I found out that it was not needed to go through the 'publish' process, but it was just a matter of waiting a few days.